# How to invoke android dynamic library(.so) in a X86 linux?

Tags: android, x86, arm

There is a prebuilt apk and I get some .so files in the lib directory of apk. Can I invoke these .so files in X86 platform? There is qemu emulator and it can run a arm linux. Is it possible to emulate an arm PC, then invoke the so library, and return the result to X86 PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Binary Translator from Intel called [libhoudini](https://www.google.com/search?q=libhoudini). This is used to run APKs containing ARM native code on Intel based Android devices. - just the case you describe.

[image]

Comment: This library is exactly what I want! Thank you!

Comment: Did you succeed in invoking these .so files in a X86 linux platform ?